# Android views id with Kotlin

Tags: android, android-layout, kotlin

I am working on project that uses Nav drawer.

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        ...
        app:headerLayout="@layout/home_nav_header" />
```

the header layout contains a TextView and an ImageView that will holds user name and user pic.
the file home_nav_header looks like this:

```
<LinearLayout ...>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/nav_drawer_user_image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/nav_header_vertical_spacing"
        app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/nav_drawer_user_name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/nav_header_vertical_spacing"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1" />

</LinearLayout>
```

In my HomeActivity, I set data this way:

```
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.home_content.*
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.home_nav_header.*
/...
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home)
        mPresenter = HomePresenter(this)

        //Fill user name
        mUser = intent.getParcelableExtra(LoginActivity.INTENT_USER)
        val userName: String = mUser.firstName + " " + mUser.lastName
        nav_drawer_user_name.text = userName

        //Fill user image
        val decodedString = Base64.decode(mUser.photoUrl, Base64.DEFAULT)
        val decodedByte = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedString, 0, decodedString.size)
        val userImageDrawable = BitmapDrawable(getResources(), decodedByte)
        nav_drawer_user_name.background = userImageDrawable
    }
```

I checked that both userName and userImageDrawable are not null.

The problemis that when i'm trying to fill data in both TextView and ImageView, the app crashs with the following error:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException:
>   findViewById(R.id.nav_drawer_user_name) must not be null

What I am missing in my code ?

Comment: Please post your activity code

Comment: May be you need to add main layout also like `import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_home.*`

Answer (score 0):

You must get the view first before you can assign a value to it.

```
   import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.home_content.*
   import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.home_nav_header.*

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_home)
            mPresenter = HomePresenter(this)

            //Fill user name
            mUser = intent.getParcelableExtra(LoginActivity.INTENT_USER)
            val userName: String = mUser.firstName + " " + mUser.lastName
            val nav_drawer_user_name = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.nav_drawer_user_name)
            nav_drawer_user_name.text = userName

            //Fill user image
            val decodedString = Base64.decode(mUser.photoUrl, Base64.DEFAULT)
            val decodedByte = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedString, 0, decodedString.size)
            val userImageDrawable = BitmapDrawable(getResources(), decodedByte)
            nav_drawer_user_name.background = userImageDrawable
        }
```

Note the `val nav_drawer_user_name = findViewById<TextView(R.id.nav_drawer_user_name)`

Comment: It didn't solve the problem. In fact, in Kotlin you can use directly the id to call the view without calling findViewById.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is an issue with kotlin android plugin, I tried this same error in onCreate, onStart and onResume but if I set text onClick of something its workes properly. if you still want to setText(or any other method of that view) you do it by tradition way

```
    val textView  = nav_view.getHeaderView(0).findViewById<TextView>(R.id.nav_drawer_user_name)
    textView.text= "new Text"
```